# latest @angular-cli does not create a project with latest angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6, angular-cli-v7

node --version

```
v10.14.2
```

npm version

```
6.4.1
```

At first, @angular-cli is not installed

`ng -version`

`'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I install the latest version of angular with:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I list global dependencies

`npm list -g --depth=0`

I get

`+-- @angular/cli@7.3.5`

I check its version

`ng --version`

I have instead of version 7.3.5 the old version 6.2.8.
Where is this old version coming from? I'm in an empty directory.

`Angular CLI: 6.2.8
Node: 10.14.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:`

When I generate a new project with

`ng new newapp`

in my package.json I have the old version of @angular-cli 6.2.8 and angular 6.1.0

`{
  "name": "newapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}`

How can I generate an @angular-cli project version 7 or 8 ?
what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you installed ionic at some point?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the quick answer but I got the same problem.
Here are the steps I followed:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm list --depth -g
   empty 
ng -v
   'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm list --depth -g
    +-- @angular/cli@7.3.5
ng -v
    Angular CLI: 6.2.8
```

So its listed as 7.3.5 but when I do ng -v I have version 6.2.8
Before I had version 6.2.8.
That means that there must be maybe a remaining version 6.2.8 somwhere.
But by the steps explained at the start it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest do follow the below commands now and check

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```